# Transform XML to PDF using XSLT with nodejs

Tags: node.js, xml, pdf, xslt

I have xml file that contains remote xsl stylesheet link. I need to convert that xml to pdf? I have tried [Prince](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prince) but it is not adding desired style. Is there any other package that i can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-pdf) in this you can set your custom template also for design purpose. I have committed a GitHub repo for you. https://github.com/vivek9716/convert_pdf please check if this is helpful.

Comment: did you try using xsl as a template. I want to generate the pdf on the fly and return to a rest call? I mean that I get a json input render over xsl template and return  byteArray as response? Please let me know if you have tried with this xml-pdf?

Comment: Actually, you can try, i just try with the xml only.